# Returns and Inlines

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to find the Kotlin equivalent to this Java return:

```
return new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

I've tried just declaring then returning like this:

```
val returnArr: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
return returnArr
```

But I get a warning that says "Variable used only in following return and can be inlined". What exactly is meant by inline? Is there a way to do this all on one line?

Comment: return intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)

Comment: Thank you! What exactly is inline though? Is that basically lambda?

Comment: It's nothing fancy, the warning basically says why to declare a variable when you are using it only in the return statement. One of the key philosophy of kotlin among others is to write less code(boilerplate or otherwise) when compared to java. You can even declare methods like this: `fun addTwoNumnbers(num1:Int, num2:Int) = num1 + num2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the context of the warning, "inlining" means removing local variables, parameters, functions, etc. that really don't need to be there, and the code would be simpler without them. For example, in the statement

```
val returnArr: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
return returnArr
```

`returnArr` serves no purpose (except perhaps when debugging), and you could replace it with

```
return intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
```

The use of the term "inlining" to refer to such simplifications is a JetBrains convention, I think, due to the existence of the "Inline" refactoring that can automate simplifications like the one we're talking about (right-click on `returnArr` and select Refactor/Inline).

The warning is not a compiler warning; it is one of many style inspections that IntelliJ does. If you like your temporary variables, I think you can disable it by going to Preferences/Editor/Inspections/Kotlin/Redundant Constructs and unchecking "Unnecessary local variable".

Comment: The usage of "inlining" here is completely standard: indirect reference to a thing being replaced with the thing itself. The most talked-about kind of inlining is for function calls, but this is the equivalent for local variables.

Comment: Greate Answer !